# Unable to login jenkins, and can't disable login option either

Tags: jenkins, tomcat7

I deployed jenkins.war to tomcat webapps. and changed security setting to "allow only login user..." without creating any users yet.

So now I am not able to login jenkins, and can not disable the login option either.

After googling around, seems it can be solved by editing config.xml file under jenkins root directory;  however, there's not such xml existing in my jenkins root dir.

How do I recover from here?

Many Thanks!

Update:

1. Actually jenkins is running on the Windows 7 OS.
2. After specifically set the environment variable as JENKINS_HOME="F:\Tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\jenkins"
3. then navigate to `http://localhost:8080/jenkins/`

I see below Error -

```
*hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.io.IOException: Unable to read F:\Tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\jenkins\config.xml
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:234)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.io.IOException: Unable to read F:\Tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\jenkins\config.xml
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:910)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:809)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:78)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:222)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to read F:\Tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\jenkins\config.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:167)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$17.run(Jenkins.java:2562)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:899)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationError: hudson.security.AuthorizationStrategy
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor5.newInstance(Unknown Source)*
```

Comment: Can you try the command `ps -aef | grep jenkin` and check `JENKINS_HOME` is the exact place where you are looking for the config.xml

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Issue was solved now :-)
>
> 1. I first changed the port of server.xml file for Tomcat
>
>    - --> Connector port="new-port" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
> 2. I then removed the JENKINS_HOME environment variable from System
>      variables definition.
> 3. then removed deployed 'jenkins' directory under 'tomcat/webapps'
>      directory
> 4. and removed everything under 'tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost'
>      directory
> 5. then restart Tomcat server
>
> Now I'm in Jenkins page without requiring a login - "Welcome to Jenkins! Please create new jobs to get started. "
>
> Hopefully, this could help others who having the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

In the Jenkins installation, I edited the `config.xml` to have `<useSecurity>` set to `false`. This enabled me to go back into Jenkins and redo my security settings.

You might need to restart the Jenkins service for this to take effect.

Comment: Why is this downvoted. If resolving the problem requires you to resolve dependency errors related to plugins in the "Manage Plugins" page, this is an appropriate answer.